# PSZoom output truncated

Tags: powershell, zoom-sdk, pszoom

Please excuse me if this is a stupid user error....
I am using PSZoom (powershell wrapper for zoom api). https://github.com/JosephMcEvoy/PSZoom
I have authenticated and have my key pair (no need to include it publicly) and have been able to output user lists, as well as update meetings with no problem.
Working with recordings is killing me.
Final goal is to list the UUIDs of all recordings in December so i can delete those specific records with a powershell script.

I have 119 recordings to work with.
I run

```
Get-ZoomAccountRecordings -AccountId me -From 2020-12-01 -To 2020-12-31 -PageSize 300
```

and get back

from            : 2020-12-01
to              : 2020-12-31
page_size       : 300
total_records   : 119
next_page_token :
meetings        :

I have removed the meetings output section - it outputs info on 4 meetings and then "..." and thats it.
I see no verbose option, I tried piping it to csv, to text file, to append..... I'm stuck... what is wrong with this command that I get only 4 results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ZoomAccountRecordings -AccountId me -From 2020-12-01 -To 2020-12-31 -PageSize 300 | out-string -Width 4096
```

This will give you a width in your output of 4096 characters. If this is unreadable, you can also  tell your environment to change your limit. To find your current enumeration limit:

```
PS > $FormatEnumerationLimit
```

The number returned is the limit to the results that can be shown in your output for collections and lists. To change it for your environment, do the following:

```
PS > $FormatEnumerationLimit=-1
```

Setting it to -1 will ensure full results display for your terminal when it comes to collections and lists.

Comment: The 4096 did not solve the issue, but the enumarationlist edit did.
Thank you, that was a parameter I did not know about.... OK, onward, now I need to (in a new question) figure out how to properly set the output to something useful.
THANK YOU!

Comment: So that just means your environment was limiting the output! Glad that helped. I'll keep an eye out for any more questions :)